# Criticism on x86_64 nasm assembly strToInt and printInt implementation

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am pretty new to assembly I would like criticism on two "methods" I have written. One converts string to int and the other prints an int to stdout. Any advise helps out.

```
bits 64

section .data
endl db 10, 0
endlLength equ $ - endl

section .bss
   string resb 100

section .text
global _start
global _strToInt
global _printInt

_start:
   mov rbp, rsp

   ;get int from user
   mov rax, 0
   mov rdi, 0
   lea rsi, [string]
   mov rdx, 100
   syscall

   ;make string to int
   push string
   call _strToInt
   pop r8

   push rax
   call _printInt
   pop  rax

   mov rax, 1
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rsi, endl
   mov rdx, endlLength
   syscall

   mov rax, 60
   mov rbx, 0
   syscall

   ;last value pushed to stack must be address to string. stores int in rax
_strToInt:
  ;prolog
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  ;save registers
  push rbx

  ;actual code
  xor rax, rax
  mov rbx, 10          ;will be used to multiply by 10 later

  mov rcx, [rbp + 16]
  cmp byte[rcx], '-'   ;check to see if value is negetive
  jne _convertStringLoop
  inc rcx              ;increment the address

  _convertStringLoop:
     xor rdx, rdx      ;clear rdx
     mul rbx           ;multiply rax by 10
     mov dl, [rcx]     ;get 1 byte from rcx address
     sub dl, '0'       ;seb by '0' to get actual value
     add rax, rdx      ;add it to rax
     inc rcx
  cmp byte[rcx], 10    ;see if new line char. exit if new line char
  je _exitConvertStringLoop
  cmp byte[rcx], 0     ;see if end of line char. exit if end of line
  jne _convertStringLoop

  _exitConvertStringLoop:
  mov rcx, [rbp + 16]
  cmp byte[rcx], '-'   ;if not negetive jump
  jne _exitStrToInt
  not rax              ;1's complement (make negetive)
  inc rax              ;2's complement (make negetive)

  _exitStrToInt:
  ;restore registers
  pop rbx
  ;epilog
  pop rbp
  ret

;last value pushed to stack will be printed
_printInt:
  ;prolog
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  ;save registers
  push rbx

  ;actual code
  mov rsi, rsp
  mov rax, [rbp + 16] ;get the value that user wants to print
  mov rbx, 10         ;will be used to divide by 10 later
  xor rcx, rcx

  cqo
  cmp rdx, -1         ;check to see if negetive
  jne _divisionLoop   ;if not negetive jump

  ;print negetive sign
  mov [rsi + 1], byte '-'
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  inc rsi
  mov rdx, 1
  syscall
  dec rsi

  ;convert to positive number
  mov rax, [rbp + 16]
  ;imul rax, -1
  dec rax
  not rax
  xor rcx, rcx

  _divisionLoop:
     xor rdx, rdx
     div rbx        ;divides number by 10 to move over last digit into rdx reg
     add dl, '0'
     dec rsi
     mov [rsi], dl
     inc rcx        ; count for how many digits added to stack
  cmp rax, 0
  jnz _divisionLoop ;jump if the division did not result in a zero

  ;print all the values
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rdx, rcx
  syscall

  ;restore register
  pop rbx
  ;epilog
  pop rbp
  ret
```

One more thing I wanted to ask was is it better to do

```
     mov rax, -20
     mov rbx, -1
     imul rbx
```

or

```
     mov rax, -20
     dec rax
     not rax
```

when I know a number is negetive and I want to turn it to a positive.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. For X86 integer negation, you'd have to argue why to avoid [the proper instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4534503).

Comment: thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Warming up

A good thing that I see missing from your program is writing comments about the function numbers and more.

```
mov rdi, 0    ; STDIN
mov rax, 0    ; SYS_READ
syscall
...
mov rdi, 1    ; STDOUT
mov rax, 1    ; SYS_WRITE
syscall

mov rdi, 0    ; OK
mov rax, 60   ; SYS_EXIT
syscall
```

Here's an improvement that you can make:

> ```
> section .data
> endl db 10, 0
> endlLength equ $ - endl
> ```

The output to STDOUT is length driven. It's not useful to zero terminated this newline. All you could get is that ASCII character 0 gets displayed needlessly.

#### There are some errors in your code

> ```
> mov rax, 60
> mov rbx, 0
> syscall
> ```

The first argument must go in `RDI`. You wrote `RBX`. Habit from 32-bit ?

---

> ```
> _convertStringLoop:
>   xor rdx, rdx      ;clear rdx
>   mul rbx           ;multiply rax by 10
>   mov dl, [rcx]     ;get 1 byte from rcx address
>   sub dl, '0'       ;seb by '0' to get actual value
>   add rax, rdx      ;add it to rax
> ```

You have misplaced that `xor rdx, rdx` instruction. The `mul rbx` instruction that follows will modify `RDX` as part of its operation. If the input that you get from the user at the keyboard is really big, then `RDX` can become non-zero! But wait! You need `RDX` to be zero so the addition can work correctly...

This will work fine zero-extending `DL` into `EDX` into `RDX`:

```
_convertStringLoop:
   mul   rbx              ; multiply rax by 10
   movzx edx, byte [rcx]  ; Get 1 byte from RCX address and put in RDX
   sub   dl, '0'          ; seb by '0' to get actual value
   add   rax, rdx         ; add it to rax
```

and this will work too and allows to not use `RBX` at all (saves many instructions):

```
_convertStringLoop:
   imul  rax, 10          ; multiply rax by 10
   movzx edx, byte [rcx]  ; Get 1 byte from RCX address and put in RDX
   sub   dl, '0'          ; seb by '0' to get actual value
   add   rax, rdx         ; add it to rax
```

---

> ```
> ;print negetive sign
> mov [rsi + 1], byte '-'
> mov rax, 1
> mov rdi, 1
> inc rsi
> mov rdx, 1
> syscall
> dec rsi
> ```

This code overwrites the value of `RBX` that you're trying to preserve on the stack!
You need to offset by a negative number or else decrement `RSI` beforehand:

```
; print negative sign
dec  rsi
mov  byte [rsi], '-'
mov  rdx, 1
mov  rdi, 1   ; STDOUT
mov  rax, 1   ; SYS_WRITE
syscall
inc  rsi
```

#### Some better ways of doing things

> ```
> cqo
> cmp rdx, -1         ;check to see if negetive
> jne _divisionLoop   ;if not negetive jump
> ```

You can test if `RAX` contains a negative number simply by testing the register with itself and then inspecting the sign flag:

```
test rax, rax
jns  _divisionLoop   ; RAX is positive
```

---

> ```
> cmp byte[rcx], '-'   ;if not negetive jump
> jne _exitStrToInt
> not rax              ;1's complement (make negetive)
> inc rax              ;2's complement (make negetive)
> ```

The instruction set offers you the `NEG` instruction to negate a number:

```
cmp  byte [rcx], '-'   ; If not negative jump
jne  _exitStrToInt
neg  rax
```

---

> ```
> cmp rax, 0
> jnz _divisionLoop ;jump if the division did not result in a zero
> ```

To find out if a register is 0, you can test it with itself and inspect the zero flag. This shaves off a byte and generally produces faster code:

```
test  rax, rax
jnz   _divisionLoop
```

Comment: Thank you so MUCH! I really do appreciate you going over my code. I'm actually  in tears of JOY!

Comment: Then good tears, I hope...

Answer (score 3):

As [Sep Roland pointed out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249137/criticism-on-x86-64-nasm-assembly-strtoint-and-printint-implementation#answer-249289), it's really important to specify the significance of the numeric constants you're using. Rather than adding comments on each line though, I'm a huge fan of using the nasm preprocessor to define C-style symbolic constants.

```
%define STDIN  0
%define STDOUT 1
%define STDERR 2

%define SYSCALL_READ  0
%define SYSCALL_WRITE 1
%define SYSCALL_EXIT  60
```

If these macros are defined in the same file, you can just use them like you would in C.

```
mov rax,SYSCALL_READ
mov rdi,STDIN
syscall
...
mov rax,SYSCALL_WRITE
mov rdi,STDOUT
syscall
```

Having thus specified what the constants represent, this frees up the space on the side for comments on why you're doing what you're doing, why you're not doing it a different way, important warnings for anyone who might later want to make changes, etc.

In other words, I prefer to use the preprocessor for the *what* and comments for the *why*. This is obviously just down to personal preference though, and to be quite honest I think most of us would prefer any comments anywhere in any format over the abyss of nothingness we usually get to wade through.

Regarding your code organization, I like the nested indentation you used, I've actually never seen that before, and it actually made me laugh. It's a great idea! I would still also recommend using [local labels](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9) because it allows you to reuse label names as long as you don't do it within the same global label.

For example:

```
_strToInt:
  ;prolog
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  ;save registers
  push rbx

  ;actual code
  xor rax, rax
  mov rbx, 10          ;will be used to multiply by 10 later

  mov rcx, [rbp + 16]
  cmp byte[rcx], '-'   ;check to see if value is negetive
  jne _convertStringLoop
  inc rcx              ;increment the address

  ._convertStringLoop:
     xor rdx, rdx      ;clear rdx
     mul rbx           ;multiply rax by 10
     mov dl, [rcx]     ;get 1 byte from rcx address
     sub dl, '0'       ;seb by '0' to get actual value
     add rax, rdx      ;add it to rax
     inc rcx
  cmp byte[rcx], 10    ;see if new line char. exit if new line char
  je _exitConvertStringLoop
  cmp byte[rcx], 0     ;see if end of line char. exit if end of line
  jne _convertStringLoop

  ._exitConvertStringLoop:
  mov rcx, [rbp + 16]
  cmp byte[rcx], '-'   ;if not negetive jump
  jne _exitStrToInt
  not rax              ;1's complement (make negetive)
  inc rax              ;2's complement (make negetive)

  ._exit:
  ;restore registers
  pop rbx
  ;epilog
  pop rbp
  ret
```

Prepending a period to your `_strToInt` subroutine labels to convert them into local labels now means you could for instance write a `_strToFloat` subroutine that also contained a sensibly named loop label called `.convertStringLoop`. There are also a billion subroutines that could reasonably contain an `._exit` label, so local labels allow you to use descriptive labels without polluting the module's global namespace.

Much less importantly, [you don't need to declare `BITS 64`](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1) in order to assemble in 64 bits. Nasm knows the output needs to be in 64 bits when you declare a 64-bit output format. This is necessary only when you want to assemble a flat binary file in long mode, since (as the documentation explains) raw binary files are probably going to be bootloaders or DOS files, both of which execute in 16-bit real mode.

Of course, there's no harm in explicitly declaring it anyways. If you felt compelled to explicitly declare the target processor of your choosing, however, I might instead suggest declaring the [CPU feature level](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.11) instead, although the default is again usually okay.

Comment: Thank you for telling me how to make local labels it saves me a lot of time!!! And I appreciate the criticism it means a lot!